# Kafka Timed out waiting for a node assignment

Tags: kubernetes, apache-kafka

I'm running a Kafka Deployment on Kubernetes (Docker Desktop) and so far the Pod is running and succsessfully
establishing a connection with Zookeeper. My Theory is that I can most likely connect to the  broker, but I'm not getting any response from it.

So when I try to connect, I'm getting this as a response after a while:

```
kafka-topics --list --bootstrap-server localhost:9092
Error while executing topic command : org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for a node assignment.
[2021-10-21 22:03:56,027] ERROR java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for a node assignment.
        at org.apache.kafka.common.internals.KafkaFutureImpl.wrapAndThrow(KafkaFutureImpl.java:45)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.internals.KafkaFutureImpl.access$000(KafkaFutureImpl.java:32)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.internals.KafkaFutureImpl$SingleWaiter.await(KafkaFutureImpl.java:89)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.internals.KafkaFutureImpl.get(KafkaFutureImpl.java:260)
        at kafka.admin.TopicCommand$AdminClientTopicService.getTopics(TopicCommand.scala:327)
        at kafka.admin.TopicCommand$AdminClientTopicService.listTopics(TopicCommand.scala:262)
        at kafka.admin.TopicCommand$.main(TopicCommand.scala:66)
        at kafka.admin.TopicCommand.main(TopicCommand.scala)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for a node assignment.
 (kafka.admin.TopicCommand$)
```

This is my deployment yaml:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
      io.bi.service: bi-kafka
  name: bi-kafka
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
      matchLabels:
          io.bi.service: bi-kafka
  strategy:
      type: Recreate
  template:
      metadata:
          labels:
              io.bi.network/maprlocal: "true"
              io.bi.service: bi-kafka
      spec:
          containers:
              -   image: wurstmeister/kafka
                  name: bi-kafka
                  ports:
                      - containerPort: 9092
                  resources:
                      limits:
                          cpu: 200m
                          memory: 500Mi
                      requests:
                          cpu: 100m
                          memory: 150Mi
                  securityContext:
                      privileged: true
                  volumeMounts:
                      -   mountPath: /var/lib/kafka/data
                          name: kafka-storage
                  env:
                      -   name: KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT
                          value: zoo1:2181
                      -   name: KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT_MS
                          value: "30000"
                      -   name: KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR
                          value: "1"
                      -   name: KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS
                          value: "PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092"
                      -   name: KAFKA_LISTENERS
                          value: "PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092"
                      -   name: KAFKA_CREATE_TOPICS
                          value: "test-topic:1:1"
                      -   name: KAFKA_ADVERTISED_PORT
                          value: "30718"
          volumes:
              -   name: kafka-storage
                  persistentVolumeClaim:
                      claimName: kafka-storage
          restartPolicy: Always
          serviceAccountName: ""
status: { }
```

This is my kafka service yaml:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: kafka-service
  labels:
    name: kafka
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 9092
    name: kafka-port
    protocol: TCP
  selector:
    app: kafka
    id: "0"
  type: LoadBalancer




 (kafka.server.KafkaConfig)
[2021-10-21 19:59:53,863] INFO [ThrottledChannelReaper-Fetch]: Starting (kafka.server.ClientQuotaManager$ThrottledChannelReaper)
[2021-10-21 19:59:53,864] INFO [ThrottledChannelReaper-Produce]: Starting (kafka.server.ClientQuotaManager$ThrottledChannelReaper)
[2021-10-21 19:59:53,866] INFO [ThrottledChannelReaper-Request]: Starting (kafka.server.ClientQuotaManager$ThrottledChannelReaper)
[2021-10-21 19:59:53,867] INFO [ThrottledChannelReaper-ControllerMutation]: Starting (kafka.server.ClientQuotaManager$ThrottledChannelReaper)
[2021-10-21 19:59:54,064] INFO Log directory /kafka/kafka-logs-bi-kafka-55cd49cf66-7m5cb not found, creating it. (kafka.log.LogManager)
[2021-10-21 19:59:54,075] INFO Loading logs from log dirs ArraySeq(/kafka/kafka-logs-bi-kafka-55cd49cf66-7m5cb) (kafka.log.LogManager)
[2021-10-21 19:59:54,163] INFO Attempting recovery for all logs in /kafka/kafka-logs-bi-kafka-55cd49cf66-7m5cb since no clean shutdown file was found (kafka.log.LogManager)
[2021-10-21 19:59:54,171] INFO Loaded 0 logs in 96ms. (kafka.log.LogManager)
[2021-10-21 19:59:54,270] INFO Starting log cleanup with a period of 300000 ms. (kafka.log.LogManager)
[2021-10-21 19:59:54,363] INFO Starting log flusher with a default period of 9223372036854775807 ms. (kafka.log.LogManager)
waiting for kafka to be ready
[2021-10-21 19:59:58,566] INFO Created ConnectionAcceptRate sensor, quotaLimit=2147483647 (kafka.network.ConnectionQuotas)
[2021-10-21 19:59:58,664] INFO Created ConnectionAcceptRate-PLAINTEXT sensor, quotaLimit=2147483647 (kafka.network.ConnectionQuotas)
[2021-10-21 19:59:58,668] INFO Updated PLAINTEXT max connection creation rate to 2147483647 (kafka.network.ConnectionQuotas)
[2021-10-21 19:59:58,675] INFO Awaiting socket connections on localhost:9092. (kafka.network.Acceptor)
[2021-10-21 19:59:59,066] INFO [SocketServer brokerId=1003] Created data-plane acceptor and processors for endpoint : ListenerName(PLAINTEXT) (kafka.network.SocketServer)
[2021-10-21 19:59:59,363] INFO [ExpirationReaper-1003-Produce]: Starting (kafka.server.DelayedOperationPurgatory$ExpiredOperationReaper)
[2021-10-21 19:59:59,364] INFO [ExpirationReaper-1003-Fetch]: Starting (kafka.server.DelayedOperationPurgatory$ExpiredOperationReaper)
[2021-10-21 19:59:59,366] INFO [ExpirationReaper-1003-DeleteRecords]: Starting (kafka.server.DelayedOperationPurgatory$ExpiredOperationReaper)
[2021-10-21 19:59:59,366] INFO [ExpirationReaper-1003-ElectLeader]: Starting (kafka.server.DelayedOperationPurgatory$ExpiredOperationReaper)
[2021-10-21 19:59:59,466] INFO [LogDirFailureHandler]: Starting (kafka.server.ReplicaManager$LogDirFailureHandler)
[2021-10-21 19:59:59,467] INFO [broker-1003-to-controller-send-thread]: Starting (kafka.server.BrokerToControllerRequestThread)
[2021-10-21 19:59:59,969] INFO Creating /brokers/ids/1003 (is it secure? false) (kafka.zk.KafkaZkClient)
[2021-10-21 20:00:00,073] INFO Stat of the created znode at /brokers/ids/1003 is: 150,150,1634846400068,1634846400068,1,0,0,107140950084223012,202,0,150
 (kafka.zk.KafkaZkClient)
[2021-10-21 20:00:00,075] INFO Registered broker 1003 at path /brokers/ids/1003 with addresses: PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092, czxid (broker epoch): 150 (kafka.zk.KafkaZkClient)
[2021-10-21 20:00:01,363] INFO [ExpirationReaper-1003-topic]: Starting (kafka.server.DelayedOperationPurgatory$ExpiredOperationReaper)
[2021-10-21 20:00:01,465] INFO [ExpirationReaper-1003-Heartbeat]: Starting (kafka.server.DelayedOperationPurgatory$ExpiredOperationReaper)
[2021-10-21 20:00:01,466] INFO [ExpirationReaper-1003-Rebalance]: Starting (kafka.server.DelayedOperationPurgatory$ExpiredOperationReaper)
[2021-10-21 20:00:02,165] INFO [GroupCoordinator 1003]: Starting up. (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupCoordinator)
[2021-10-21 20:00:02,167] INFO [GroupCoordinator 1003]: Startup complete. (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupCoordinator)
[2021-10-21 20:00:02,465] INFO [ProducerId Manager 1003]: Acquired new producerId block (brokerId:1003,blockStartProducerId:2000,blockEndProducerId:2999) by writing to Zk with path version 3 (kafka.coordinator.transaction.ProducerIdManager)
[2021-10-21 20:00:02,576] INFO [TransactionCoordinator id=1003] Starting up. (kafka.coordinator.transaction.TransactionCoordinator)
[2021-10-21 20:00:02,764] INFO [Transaction Marker Channel Manager 1003]: Starting (kafka.coordinator.transaction.TransactionMarkerChannelManager)
[2021-10-21 20:00:02,764] INFO [TransactionCoordinator id=1003] Startup complete. (kafka.coordinator.transaction.TransactionCoordinator)
[2021-10-21 20:00:03,764] INFO [ExpirationReaper-1003-AlterAcls]: Starting (kafka.server.DelayedOperationPurgatory$ExpiredOperationReaper)
[2021-10-21 20:00:04,567] INFO [/config/changes-event-process-thread]: Starting (kafka.common.ZkNodeChangeNotificationListener$ChangeEventProcessThread)
[2021-10-21 20:00:04,963] INFO [SocketServer brokerId=1003] Starting socket server acceptors and processors (kafka.network.SocketServer)
[2021-10-21 20:00:05,065] INFO [SocketServer brokerId=1003] Started data-plane acceptor and processor(s) for endpoint : ListenerName(PLAINTEXT) (kafka.network.SocketServer)
[2021-10-21 20:00:05,066] INFO [SocketServer brokerId=1003] Started socket server acceptors and processors (kafka.network.SocketServer)
[2021-10-21 20:00:05,166] INFO Kafka version: 2.7.1 (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser)
[2021-10-21 20:00:05,263] INFO Kafka commitId: 61dbce85d0d41457 (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser)
[2021-10-21 20:00:05,264] INFO Kafka startTimeMs: 1634846405066 (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser)
[2021-10-21 20:00:05,266] INFO [KafkaServer id=1003] started (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
[2021-10-21 20:00:05,564] INFO [broker-1003-to-controller-send-thread]: Recorded new controller, from now on will use broker 1003 (kafka.server.BrokerToControllerRequestThread)
creating topics: test-topic:1:1
```

Kubernetes Version: V.1.19.7
Docker Engine Version: V20.10.5
Kafka Version: 5.4.1

Comment: 1) You should use the kafka service name, not localhost 2) Why not use Helm charts or operators?

Comment: 3) What is this - `KAFKA_ADVERTISED_PORT`? You never used the value for this anywhere as far as exposing that port on any network interface (not in the listeners and not in the containerPort, and not in the loadbalancer)

Comment: I suggest you start here and read the documentation closely - https://strimzi.io/

Comment: I've tried using the kafka service name (kafka-service), but it didn't work:
`Socket server failed to bind to kafka-service:9092: Address not available.`  I might consider testing strimzi if I'm unable to make the above setup work.

Comment: Outside of the cluster, that name wouldn't exist. You'd need to `kubectl exec` into a pod first

Comment: @OneCricketeer The above error is coming from within the kafka pod. I was checking `kubectl logs bi-kafka-agg4sn3`

Comment: Okay, well, still, the advertised listeners you've set don't allow the service name to even work. Have you tried yet to use Strimzi?

Comment: @OneCricketeer Yes, kinda. I've tried the helm setup of [confluent](https://github.com/confluentinc/cp-helm-chart) which basically worked, besides not giving me any configurationoption  since it's only free for testing.

Comment: @OneCricketeer Anyway, I think the main issue here is, that I'm using Docker Desktop which doesn't seem to have a LoadBalancer, so this explains why it's not possible to expose an external ip, since the corresponding service will remain stuck in pending.

Comment: Which version of Kubernetes did you use? It is important to reproduce your problem.